# How to turn a complicated graph into Json Graph Format?

Tags: postgresql, json, graph

So having such normalized Postgres 13/14 graph of item joins:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  item_id     serial PRIMARY KEY,
  title text
);
CREATE TABLE joins (
  id          serial PRIMARY KEY,
  item_id     int,
  child_id    int
);
INSERT INTO items (item_id,title) VALUES
  (1,'PARENT'),
  (2,'LEVEL 2'),
  (3,'LEVEL 3.1'),
  (4,'LEVEL 4.1'),
  (5,'LEVEL 4.2'),
  (6,'LEVEL 3.2');
INSERT INTO joins (item_id, child_id) VALUES
  (1,2),
  (2,3),
  (3,2),
  (3,5),
  (2,6);
```

How to turn it into a JSON Graph Format document containing item columns as fields?

Comment: What database and what version ? And what json format ? Do you mean GraphSON ? Or some custom notation, and if so you need to describe it - or better, give an example of the output you expect

Comment: Also how do you want the JSON result ? As a JSON object in your database (assuming the database allows that).  Or as a file ?

Comment: As a JSON JGF (or similar) object output